# Swift 3 unwind segue from view controller C to A also executes code of view controller B

Tags: swift, unwind-segue

`ViewController A` has the function:

`@IBAction fund backToViewControllerA (segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}`

`ViewController C`: via storyboard a unwind segue was created (view controller to exit, with an identifier and action)

When going from `A` to `B` to `C` and then pressing the button in `C` to `start the unwind`, the `ViewController C` unwinds to `A`. So far so good...

Problem: in the meantime, during the unwind, also the `viewDidAppear()` of `B` is executed.

Question: how do I prevent the code of `ViewController B` to be executed?

Comment: Provide more code

Comment: What code is being ran? The code in view controller B's viewDidAppear()? The code in an unwind inside view controller B?

Comment: The code in ViewWillAppear of view controller B is being run.

Answer (score 1):

FYI. I test a example.
If A is in UINavigationController. A > B > C > A will good.
But if A is just a UIViewController. The code of B.viewDidAppear will be executed.

Comment: Good job! So there you have it.

Comment: Thanks! So my problem is real. Now I am preventing the execution of the code in B by first checking a variable value. If it is zero no execution. I set it to zero before going to C.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something wrong. I just created this example project to show that it is not the case.

https://github.com/Sethmr/TestUnwindSegue

Download it and see that viewDidAppear() in view controller B never gets called.